# R: sorting a row at a time - strange things happening

Tags: r, sorting, rows

I have some data that looks like this:

```
    > head(trim)
          origin       X.1                 X.2  X.3  X.4  X.5
    1  017003001 257056001                <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
    6  017035001 017017001           017039001 <NA> <NA> <NA>
    8  017038003 087041002                <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
    11 027001001 027006006 027054001/027054003 <NA> <NA> <NA>
    12 027002002 027081001           117016001 <NA> <NA> <NA>
    15 027006006 027001001           027006001 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

I'm attempting to sort across each row like so:

```
    for(lc in 1:nrow(trim)){
      trim[lc,] <-sort(trim[lc,],na.last=TRUE)
    }
```

The output like so:

```
    > head(trim)
          origin       X.1                 X.2  X.3  X.4  X.5
    1  017003001 257056001                <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
    6  017017001         6           017039001 <NA> <NA> <NA>
    8  017038003 087041002                <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
    11 027001001 027006006 027054001/027054003 <NA> <NA> <NA>
    12 027002002 027081001           117016001 <NA> <NA> <NA>
    15 027001001 027006001                  15 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Eh...so whats going on here with this weirdness? Why are the row names being sorted and seemingly replacing some genuine entries?

Comment: Most likely you have a dataframe, so you are not even sorting numerically. Try trim<-as.matrix(trim)

Comment: Actually they are characters - sorry I should have said that. But yes your solution seems to have worked! Many thanks

Comment: Yay! Now let's wait the gurus to understand why it works like this in a data.frame

Comment: Please post dput(head(trim)), that would be helpful to understand that exactly is going on.

Comment: Well my problem is fixed now, but I would be curious to know why this happens. dput(head(trim)) gives a huge output - the origin column is a factor variable with 18,000+ levels printed in the dput - I don't think I should post that here